# Como adicionar uma barra de rolagem no PopUp com css?

Tags: css

Eu tenho o PopUp abaixo que quando eu diminuo a tela ele não cria a barra de rolagem não sendo possível ver o conteúdo completo.

Como posso criar uma barra de rolagem para quando o navegador estiver em um tamanho menor?

Tela Cheia - Normal:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tela Menor - Perco parte do conteúdo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```js
function OcultarDiv() {
            var meuDialogConteudo = document.getElementById("meuDialog");
            meuDialogConteudo.style.display = "none";
        }

        function MostrarDiv() {
            var meuDialogConteudo = document.getElementById("meuDialog");
            meuDialogConteudo.style.display = "block";
        }
```

```css
 #meuDialog {            
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0; 
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0; 
            right: 0; 
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            padding: 20px;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }

        #meuDialogConteudo {
            position: fixed;
            width: 600px; 
            height: 600px;
            top: 50%;
            margin-top: -300px; 
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -300px;
            border: 1px double black; 
            background-color: deepskyblue; 
            overflow-y: auto;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Exemplo - PopUp001</title>
</head>
  
<body>    
      <div id="meuDialog">
            <div id="meuDialogConteudo">
                <input id="meuBotaoOcultar" type="button" onclick="OcultarDiv();" value="X" style="float: right; margin: 6px; background-color: red;" />                  
                <p>
                    Eu sou um popup criado com div e javascript sem usar jQuery.
                </p>                             
            </div>
        </div>

        <input id="meuBotaoMostrar" type="button" onclick="MostrarDiv();" value="Mostrar" style="margin: 6px; background-color: deepskyblue;" />     
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi no seu css, você quer uma div fixa no centro da tela, correto?

Answer (score 1):

Essa barra de rolagem "não está funcionando" porque você deixou a posição fixa e setou uma margem no topo.

Minha sugestão é você criar uma [media](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp) para mudar esse estilo quando diminuir a tela.

Essas medias são utilizadas para deixar o site responsivo, dentro delas você vai adaptando seu estilo.

```
@media (max-width: 800px), (max-height: 600px) {

  #meuDialogConteudo {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -200px; 
  }  

}
```

Veja no funcionando no [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4shr0nv8/).

Answer (score 0):

Use o atributo `overflow: auto`, isso fará com que uma barra de scroll apareça assim que a altura ou largura da div ultrapasse a altura ou largura definida.

Comment: Já coloquei, não muda nada :(

Answer (score 0):

Só usar o `overflow: auto`, que o scroll aparece.

Comment: Já coloquei, não muda nada :(